# How to access database connection from a Rocket's fairing?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-rocket, rust-sqlx

I'm trying to use database connection from a Rocket's `on_ignite` fairing:

```rust
use sqlx::{ self, FromRow };
use rocket::fairing::{self, Fairing, Info, Kind};
use rocket::{Build, Rocket};

use crate::database::PostgresDb;
    
#[derive(FromRow)]
struct TableRow {
  column_a: String,
  column_b: String
}

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for TableRow {
  fn info(&self) -> Info {
    Info {
      name: "Cache table row",
      kind: Kind::Ignite,
    }
  }

  async fn on_ignite(&self, rocket: Rocket<Build>) -> fairing::Result {
    let mut db = rocket
      .state::<Connection<PostgresDb>>()
      .expect("Unable to find db connection.");

    let row = sqlx::query_as::<_, TableRow>("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1;")
      .fetch_one(&mut db)
      .await
      .unwrap();

    fairing::Result::Ok(rocket.manage(row))
  }
}
```

The problem is I get following rust error during `.fetch_one(&mut db)`:

```
the trait bound `&mut rocket_db_pools::Connection<PostgresDb>: Executor<'_>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `Executor<'c>`:
  <&'c mut PgConnection as Executor<'c>>
  <&'c mut PgListener as Executor<'c>>
  <&'c mut PoolConnection<Postgres> as Executor<'c>>
  <&'t mut Transaction<'c, Postgres> as Executor<'t>>
  <&sqlx::Pool<DB> as Executor<'p>>rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
cache_rbac_on_ignite.rs(56, 14): required by a bound introduced by this call
query_as.rs(132, 17): required by a bound in `QueryAs::<'q, DB, O, A>::fetch_all`
```

I tried solution suggested here: [How to get the database Connection in rocket.rs Fairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394258/how-to-get-the-database-connection-in-rocket-rs-fairing/68394259#68394259). but it did not work out.
Here is the code:

```rust
use sqlx::{ self, FromRow, Database };
use rocket::fairing::{self, Fairing, Info, Kind};
use rocket::{Build, Rocket};

use crate::database::PostgresDb;
    
#[derive(FromRow)]
struct TableRow {
  column_a: String,
  column_b: String
}

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for TableRow {
  fn info(&self) -> Info {
    Info {
      name: "Cache table row",
      kind: Kind::Ignite,
    }
  }

  async fn on_ignite(&self, rocket: Rocket<Build>) -> fairing::Result {
    let mut db = PostgresDb::get_one(rocket).await.unwrap();

    let row = sqlx::query_as::<_, TableRow>("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1;")
      .fetch_one(&mut db)
      .await
      .unwrap();

    fairing::Result::Ok(rocket.manage(row))
  }
}
```

I get following rust error on line `let mut db = PostgresDb::get_one(rocket).await.unwrap();`:

```
no function or associated item named `get_one` found for struct `PostgresDb` in the current scope
function or associated item not found in `PostgresDb`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
mod.rs(8, 1): function or associated item `get_one` not found for this struct
```

What is the right way to use database connection inside of the fairing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer. Here is what worked for me:

```rust
use rocket::fairing::{self, Fairing, Info, Kind};
use rocket::{Build, Rocket};
use rocket_db_pools::{ sqlx::{ self, FromRow }, Database };

use crate::database::PostgresDb;
    
#[derive(FromRow)]
struct TableRow {
  column_a: String,
  column_b: String
}

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for TableRow {
  fn info(&self) -> Info {
    Info {
      name: "Cache table row",
      kind: Kind::Ignite,
    }
  }

  async fn on_ignite(&self, rocket: Rocket<Build>) -> fairing::Result {
    let db = PostgresDb::fetch(&rocket).unwrap();
    let mut conn = db.aquire().await.unwrap();

    let row = sqlx::query_as::<_, TableRow>("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1;")
      .fetch_one(&mut conn)
      .await
      .unwrap();

    fairing::Result::Ok(rocket.manage(row))
  }
}
```